# Access iframe contents

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the length of child nodes from an iframe. I have:

```
<HTML>
<iframe name = "iframetest">
    <DIV id="Counties">
            <INPUT id="1" onclick=HandleClick(this); type=checkbox CHECKED value=""><LABEL title="Checkbox 1">Checkbox 1</LABEL>
            <INPUT id="2" onclick=HandleClick(this); type=checkbox CHECKED value=""><LABEL title="Checkbox 2">Checkbox 1</LABEL>
    </DIV>
</iframe>
</HTML>
```

I am running (without the iframe)

```
alert(document.getElementById('Counties').childNodes.length)
```

I have tried

`alert(document.frames[0].getElementById('Counties').childNodes.length)`
`alert(document.frames[0].contentDocument().getElementById('Counties').childNodes.length)`
`alert(document.frames('iframetest').framegetElementById('Counties').childNodes.length)`

None of these seem to work. Thanks for any help.

Edit: I should mention that the end goal is to use this as a bookmarklet, so not using any libraries would be favored.

Comment: Try window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')

Comment: Are those actual child nodes of the iframe (i.e. the alternative content for browsers that don't support frames) or are they in a different document?

Comment: What error messages are displayed in the Console of the developer tools when you run those various alert statements?

Comment: Attempted here. Still the same issue. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/c6my3t51/1/) Thanks for your help though!